# OneToMany relationship issues

Tags: symfony, one-to-many

I have two entities, `PartenairePermission` and `StructurePermission`, I'm trying to get properties from the other entity in a `One To Many` relationship.

Which was working great with the `one to one` relationship but I modified it for a `One To Many` relationship and now I can't access the properties anymore

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "setIsMembersRead" of class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection".

The idea of the script below is when the property is modified in `PartenairePermission`, it modified the property in `StructurePermission` too.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

PartenaireController: [EDITED]

```
 #[Route('/{id}/activate-permission', name: 'app_partenaire_activate-permission', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
public function activatePermission(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Request $request, PartenaireRepository $partenaireRepository, MailerInterface $mailer): Response
{

    $partenairePermission = $entityManager->getRepository(PartenairePermission::class)->findOneBy([ // get the id of the partenaire
        'id' => $request->get('id'),
    ]);

    $partenairePermission->setIsMembersRead(!$partenairePermission->isIsMembersRead()); // set the value of the permission to the opposite of what it is ( for toggle switch )
    $structurePermission = $partenairePermission->getPermissionStructure();

    foreach ($structurePermission as $structurePermission) {
        $structurePermission->setIsMembersRead($partenairePermission->isIsMembersRead());
    }


    $entityManager->persist($partenairePermission);
    $entityManager->flush();
```

PartenairePermission.php :

```
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'permission_partenaire', targetEntity: StructurePermission::class, orphanRemoval: true)]
private Collection $permission_structure;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->permission_structure = new ArrayCollection();
} /**
 * @return Collection<int, StructurePermission>
 */
public function getPermissionStructure(): Collection
{
    return $this->permission_structure;
}

public function addPermissionStructure(StructurePermission $permissionStructure): self
{
    if (!$this->permission_structure->contains($permissionStructure)) {
        $this->permission_structure->add($permissionStructure);
        $permissionStructure->setPermissionPartenaire($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removePermissionStructure(StructurePermission $permissionStructure): self
{
    if ($this->permission_structure->removeElement($permissionStructure)) {
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($permissionStructure->getPermissionPartenaire() === $this) {
            $permissionStructure->setPermissionPartenaire(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

StructurePermission.php :

```
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(fetch: "EAGER", inversedBy: 'permission_structure')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?PartenairePermission $permission_partenaire = null;
public function getPermissionPartenaire(): ?PartenairePermission
    {
        return $this->permission_partenaire;
    }

    public function setPermissionPartenaire(?PartenairePermission $permission_partenaire): self
    {
        $this->permission_partenaire = $permission_partenaire;

        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you have to work different since you changed the association type:

```
 $structurePermission = $partenairePermission->getPermissionStructure();
```

this will return a Collection (instead of a single Object as with your former One-to-One relationship).

and then something like:

```
foreach($structurePermission as $permission) {
   // here you call your set/get/is for an Object within the Collection
}
```